# Running two versions of a site from same Yii code

Tags: php, yii

I have two versions of my project. For one i use a different CSS and index page and for another i  use different. Rest of the things that is controller, models and components are same. The only difference is in view(one or two files) and CSS.

Is there any way to manage this? `Like when the URL is URL1 then use CSS1/View1 folder and when url is URL@ use CSS2/view2 folder.` I have gone through the [modules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.module#using-module) section of Yii but i don't think they are what i need here.

So now I started to use themes. My folder structure is like:

```
 WebRoot
    - assests
    - css
    - images
    - protected
    - themes
      - theme1
        -views
          -site
          -layout
          -template
           - theme1
      -theme2
        -views
          -site
          -layout
          -template
```

In my controller I have done this:

```
  public function init() {
    if (SITE_TITLE == 'xxxxx')
      Yii::app()->theme = 'theme1';
    else
      Yii::app()->theme = 'theme2';
    parent::init();
  }
```

Which sets theme correctly.  but i keep getting file not found as renderer is looking in protected.

Comment: Please add to post you directory structures (interesting your protected, assets and themes directories) and configs of both versions

Answer (score 1):

I think, you need use themes. Here is documentation: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.theming

**UPDATED** after discussion
Trouble in `ETwigViewRenderer` and it working with themes

Comment: Yes, I used themes. My theme is also changing as per site but i have made a change in on of the HTML files in theme but change in not reflected. Do i need to remove my views from protected?

Comment: No, you don't need cleat views from protected. You need create different layouts: /theme1/layouts/main.php and /theme2/layouts/main.php and there connecting different css files. Yes, and check if valid links to them

Comment: My twig renderer is still looking in protected to get the theme folder. ANd i get not found because themes is outside the protected folder.

Comment: Are you correctly set in configs path to theme folder: `Simply configure the basePath and the baseUrl properties of the themeManager application component to be the desired ones.` and configure setting `'theme'=> <theme name>` in configs of both versions?

Comment: If you corrected sets in `/protected/config/main.php` config `'components' => array('themeManager' => array('basePath' => dirname(__FILE__).'../../themes'))` - than I don't know why your code doesn't see new layout. If for setting theme name you using Controller::init (I prefer for different configs for different versions and including file with the same configs) than you may use `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile("path/to/need/file.css");` without `Yii::app()->theme = ...;`

Comment: I am sure about this. In my controller action when i print Yii::app()->theme it gives me correct theme and path but when i print $this->getViewPath it gives me path inside protected.

Comment: Ok, I found solution, in your controller set property `public $layout = 'application.views.layouts.main'` (with you application alias). Problem in the default layout value of `//layouts/main`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40310/discussion-between-sankalp-mishra-and-creator)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change entire layout, perhaps this is a good way to do:

[Setting Layout in Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/493/how-to-setting-layouts-in-yii/)

In case you want only to change css they why don't you rely on request uri or domain name?

```
Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true)
```

Comment: I have two installs with diffrent URL(s). You mean I should check URL using Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true) and then decide the layout?

Comment: If I understood you correctly yes. I meant same only.
Since only view are changed, set layout as per wiki.